# SaveAs OK in excel 2013 but ignores filename in 2003

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I have a code in excel VBA that saves a workbook with a coded path and filename which works perfectly on my computer at home running windows 8 and office 2013. 
When I try to use it on my work computer which runs windows XP and office 2003 it ignores the coded path and file name and opens the save as dialogue box which defaults to the My Documents directory.

The intent is for the users at work to click save and the file will automatically go to a network drive with a personalised filename. They should not have to select a path or filename.

I have been testing with the path `C:\Temp\` and saving a plain .XLS file which should work on both versions of Excel.

I tried it without disabling alerts and it gave no clues as to why it ignores the path and filename. I have also tried `fileformat:=xlnormal` etc. with no luck.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
Sub FeedBackSave()

' Save the Feedback worksheet created by the user to the network drive using the path copied from
' the Management workhseet cell A11, the resource name copied from cell A1 and todays date as the filename.

  Dim wsh As Worksheet
  Dim nme, pth, TodaysDate As String

  TodaysDate = format(Now, "dd-mm-yy")
  nme = Range("A1").Value
  pth = Worksheets("Management").Range("A11").Value

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' Prevents alerts like incorrect file type or overwrite file y/n to permit 1 click save

'Save Feedback worksheet

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True, Filename:=pth & "FeedBack " & nme & " " & TodaysDate & ".xls"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: "*This is my first post so let me know if I make a formatting error.*" Well, the first thing is to not include commentary like that in questions! That's what comments (like this one you're reading right now) are for.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett- The OP does not have enough reps to make comments.

Comment: @Davesexcel: No privilege needed to comment on own posts.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, Davesexcel has been here 2 years and forgot that, you expect a guy who's been here 2 hours to know that in the first place?

Comment: @FreeMan: No, I'm expecting a guy who's been here 2 hours to not even conjecture about whether some (nonexistent) self-commenting privileges are required — and just go ahead and write a comment as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Saveas Before you close the workbook, might help., check the ranges, not sure if they are on the same sheet or not.

```
Sub FeedBackSave()

' Save the Feedback worksheet created by the user to the network drive using the path copied from
' the Management workhseet cell A11, the resource name copied from cell A1 and todays date as the filename.

    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim nme As String, pth As String, TodaysDate As String, FName As String
    Set ws = Worksheets("Management")
    TodaysDate = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy")
    nme = Range("A1").Value
    pth = ws.Range("A11").Value
    FName = pth & nme & "-" & TodaysDate & ".xls"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = 0
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs FileName:=FName
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried something similar (saving before closing) but will give this a go tomorrow. Regarding the variables, if I use the debug tool it shows the variables are set correctly. Do you think it could have something to do with the security settings not allowing a macro to save a file?

Comment: Step through the code and see what each variable equals, make sure the path ends with a \

Comment: I decided to break it down to a simple one liner and place the following code in a new blank workbook. It has the same problem, works OK at home but ignores the path and filename at work. It just opens the save as dialogue box and waits for user input.

Comment: Can't figure out how to format code in a comment  here is the code    Sub FeedBackSave()
 
 
 
    Dim FName As String
 

    FName = "C:\temp\Test.xls"
 
    With ActiveWorkbook
 
        .SaveAs Filename:=FName
 
        '.Close
 
    End With
 
End Sub